# Using temp tables within Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am pretty new to Oracle. Here is what I am trying to do inside a complex oracle stored procedure:

```
-- Create a temp table from the below query. Lets call it MyTempTable
    SELECT  a.Id, a.Due_Date, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date,LAG(a.Id,1) over (order by Id) as Prev_Id, 
            LAG(a.End_Date,1) over (order by a.End_Date) as Prev_End_Dat
    FROM  myTable a
    order by a.Id

-- On MyTempTable
    update myTempTable
    set a.Id = ' '
    and a.End_Date = ''
    where a.Id <> a.Prev_Id

-- Once i apply this rule, I need to do the following
    select * from MyTempTable
```

I thought that putting a pseudo code would help to understand exactly what I am trying to accomplish.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are new to Oracle but familiar with some other database, temporary tables in Oracle are very different from temporary tables in many other databases.  A temporary table definition in Oracle is global-- your temporary table has to be created outside the procedure and would be visible to everyone just like a permanent table.  The data you insert, however, is local to your current session or transaction (depending on the definition of the table).

You could, therefore, create a temporary table outside your procedure (I'm basing my data types on the names of the columns-- your `UPDATE` statement implies, however, that at least `id`, `end_date`, and `prev_id` must be `varchar2` columns)

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable( 
  id            integer,
  due_date      date,
  start_date    date,
  end_date      date,
  prev_id       integer,
  prev_end_date date
);
```

You'd then use that temporary table in your code just like you would a permanent table (so the `order by` in your `select` is pointless)

```
INSERT INTO myTempTable( id, due_date, start_date, end_date, prev_id, prev_end_date )
  SELECT  a.Id, a.Due_Date, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date,
          LAG(a.Id,1) over (order by Id) as Prev_Id, 
          LAG(a.End_Date,1) over (order by a.End_Date) as Prev_End_Dat
    FROM  myTable a;
```

That would work.  But it's not a particularly common thing to do in Oracle.  It's pretty rare in Oracle to use a temporary table.  In this case, I'd just implement your rule as part of the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT (case when id != prev_id
              then ' '
              else id 
          end) id,
       (case when id != prev_id 
             then null
             else end_date
         end) end_date,
       due_date,
       start_date,
       prev_id,
       prev_end_date
  FROM (SELECT  a.Id, a.Due_Date, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date,
                LAG(a.Id,1) over (order by Id) as Prev_Id, 
                LAG(a.End_Date,1) over (order by a.End_Date) as Prev_End_Dat
          FROM  myTable a);
```

Be aware also that (unless you're using new features of 12c), a stored procedure can't just run a `SELECT` statement to return a result to a caller.  A stored procedure can have an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` and open a cursor using a `SELECT` statement that the caller can then fetch from.

Comment: Thanks Justin, this worked for me! However, it did not require me to create a global temp table. I am not sure if this too is a temp table but i have the code as shown below. Thanks for your help!                                                       TempTable as(SELECT  a.Id, a.Due_Date, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date,LAG(a.Id,1) over (order by Id) as Prev_Id, 
            LAG(a.End_Date,1) over (order by a.End_Date) as Prev_End_Dat
    FROM  myTable a
    order by a.Id)

Comment: @KunalNair - I'm not sure if you are saying that you created a permanent table doing a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` or whether you are saying that you used a `WITH` clause in your `SELECT` statement.  The `WITH` clause would be an entirely reasonable way of structuring the single `SELECT` statement without using an inline view.  A permanent table would be problematic in a multi-user environment.

Comment: I used the WITH statement.